# convexity and a non-decreasing function?

Tags: functions, convex-analysis

I need to check that this function is non-decreasing:

$$ f(x) = \frac{g(x)}{x}, $$

where $g(x)=\log[\text{E}(|X|^x)]$ is the $x$'th absolute moment of random variable $X$ which is proved that is a *convex* and *non-decreasing* function of $x$; $x>0$.

(Thanks in advance for any comments & answers.)

Comment: This is false in general: consider $g(x)=x+1$. Then $f(x) = 1 + 1/x$ which is decreasing.

Comment: But $x + 1$ is not strictly convex.

Comment: nobody said it has to be.

Comment: Thanks @amakelov. But, I think it is just a convex function not affine.

Comment: @amakelov True  but there may have been a mistake.  As it happens, the question has been edited but in a different way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It suffices to show that $e^{f(x)}$ is increasing, and
$$e^{f(x)} = \mathbb{E}[|X|^x]^{1/x}$$
So now we want to show that $\mathbb{E}[|X|^x]^{1/x} \geq \mathbb{E}[|X|^y]^{1/y}$ whenever $x\geq y$, which follows from the power mean inequality.

**Edit:** to prove the power mean inequality in this case, we can use Holder's inequality: namely, it tells us that with $p=x/y>1$ and $q=\frac{p}{p-1}$ we have 
$$\mathbb{E}[(|X|^y)^p]^{1/p}\mathbb{E}[1^q] \geq \mathbb{E}[|X|^y]$$
which decodes to what we want.

Comment: I am wondering is there another way using the direct usage of convexity and being non-decreasing of $g(x)$ for proving this?